# Save ppt as pdf via applescript with Preview.app

Tags: applescript

I write script to convert xls to pdf with applescript.
Here is my code:

```
set the_file to (choose file) 
tell application "Preview" 
    activate 
    open the_file 
end tell 
tell application "System Events" 
    tell process "Preview" 
        keystroke "p" with command down 
        tell front window 
            UI elements 
        end tell 
    end tell 
end tell
```

When i run script, i have error in

```
keystroke "p" with command down
```

whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need the keyword `using` instead of the keyword `with`. So, the erroneous line should read:

```
keystroke "p" using command down
```